# Menuitem command binding to ViewModel in UserControl located in Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window with `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <central:CentralView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MainWindowModels}" />

</Grid>
```

CentralView is UserControl with DataGrid and DataGrid ContextMenu. Also, i have simple class witch implements ICommand interface and static Command class where stored all commands:

```
static CentralViewBaseCommands _goToEti;
public static CentralViewBaseCommands GoToEti => _goToEti ?? new 

    CentralViewBaseCommands(GoToExternalWindow);
    private static void GoToExternalWindow(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is GridContextMenuInfo)
        {
            object record = (obj as GridRecordContextMenuInfo)?.Record;
            CentralDataGridModel mwSfDgModel = (CentralDataGridModel)record;

            if (mwSfDgModel != null)
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }
```

CentralViewBaseCommands :

```
public class CentralViewBaseCommands : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public CentralViewBaseCommands(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public CentralViewBaseCommands(Action<object> execute,Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _execute(parameter);
}
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Code of MenuItem is following (Which located in UserControl):

```
<MenuItem Header="Исправление ошибок">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=command:CentralViewCommands.GoToEti}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
              Header="Удаление ошибочно внесенной техники">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid Width="32"
                          Height="32"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Path Width="26"
                          Height="26"
                          Margin="0,0,0,0"

                          Fill="#FFFF0000"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                          Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

So, the problem is following. When i click on menu item command executed as i expect, but if i bind command to command in `UserControl` `ViewModel (DelegateCommand<>) Command="{Binding CommandInViewModel}"` nothing is happening and command not executing.
Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because this line:

```
public static CentralViewBaseCommands GoToEti => _goToEti ?? new CentralViewBaseCommands(GoToExternalWindow);
```

is always generating a new instance of `CentralViewBaseCommands`.

Try this instead:

```
public static CentralViewBaseCommands GoToEti { get; } = new CentralViewBaseCommands(GoToExternalWindow);
```

And remove `_goToEti`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your corrected version should remove the `{ get; }`; that won't compile.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Its true, but, i want to use command in ViewModel class (DataContext of CentralView ). Like this: private DelegateCommand<object> _goToEti and use in ViewModel class. But, in ViewModel class that command not executed

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio you are using that the { get; } won't compile?
http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2015/06/30/whatrsquos-new-in-c-6.0-auto-property-initializers.aspx